# data binding option to text not work in jsviews-jqueryui-widgets

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

If used selectmenu and bind data to option text like this:

```
{^{selectmenu selectedAlbum}}
    <option value="-">Please select</option>
    {^{for albums}}
        <option data-link="value{:id} {:name} selected{:id == ~root.selectedAlbum}">                                                            </option>
    {{/for}}
{{/selectmenu}}
```

And bind property "name" like so:

```
<input data-link="albums[selectedAlbum].name" />
```

So when change the property "name" then change DOM Elements  but widget does not refresh.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

[example code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g03ducqd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI selectmenu widget hides the `<option>` and `<select>` elements and instead uses `<li>` elements to show the options list. Also it does not listen to changes in the `<option>` elements. So when the option elements change, the change is not reflected in the displayed `<li>`s.

If you use a regular `<select>` element then your scenario will work. But if you want to use the jQuery UI selectmenu, you need to force the refresh.

Here is one way to do that:

```
$.observable(app.albums).observeAll(function() {
  // Refresh the view if albums change
  $.view("#content").get(true, "selectmenu").parent.refresh();
});
```

See:

- http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/xh9r8afd/ for an updated version of your jsfiddle
- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvviewobject@refresh - documentation
- http://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@get - documentation

Comment: Thank! It helped me. However, it is not optimal for use in larger obgects and i had to use filter. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5smy2ky7)

Comment: It may be possible to do so  `$.observable(app.albums).observeAll(...,"name");`